# Only specified data from a string SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

I have a review column in a table which has multiple strings formats like below

Example strings:

```
'05012:000000:  :0:00000000|00647:000000:  :0:00000000|00283:000000:  :0:00000000|'
'05012:000000:  :0:00000000|00025:000000:  :0:00000000|00647:000000:  :0:00000000|'
'05012:000000:  :0:00000000|02095:000000:  :0:00000000|00647:000000:  :0:00000000|'
'05012:000000:  :0:00000000|00647:000000:  :0:00000000|' 
'05081:023931:DF:9:20230111|00604:023931:XX:9:20230111|02470:023931:XX:9:20230111|00655:023931:XX:9:20230111|00464:023931:XX:9:20230111|02130:023931:XX:9:20230111|'
```

I need to get output like as below for the above strings.

**The End Points are, [The End Points are "|" , ":" ]**

Example strings: [output]

```
'05012,00647,00283'
'05012,00025,00647'
'05012,02095,00647'
'05012,00647', 
'05081,00604,02470,00655,00464,02130'
```

I have tried with REPLACE() with SUBTRING() string functions in SQL Server, but I couldn't get the above output.

Comment: Please provide repeatable example:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `replace(replace(replace(col, ' ', ''), ':', ''), '000000000000000|', ',')`

Comment: It is not working for this format -->
'05081:023931:DF:9:20230111|00604:023931:XX:9:20230111|02470:023931:XX:9:20230111|' (The End Points are  "|" , ":" )

Comment: What's the limit on the number of repetitions within a single value? What version of SQL Server? Does this have to be a single query vs stored procedure/batch?

Answer (score 0):

### You can use STRING_SPLIT and STRING_AGG :-

### **https://dbfiddle.uk/db5FGFoF**

```
 Create table Temp_Tbl (Comments varchar(500));
```

---

```
 INSERT INTO Temp_Tbl
 VALUES('05012:000000:  :0:00000000|00647:000000:  :0:00000000|00283:000000:  :0:00000000|'),
 ('05012:000000:  :0:00000000|00025:000000:  :0:00000000|00647:000000:  :0:00000000|'),
 ('05012:000000:  :0:00000000|02095:000000:  :0:00000000|00647:000000:  :0:00000000|')
```

---

```
 with cte as 
 (select Comments, value as Value1 from Temp_Tbl cross apply STRING_SPLIT(Comments,'|') 
 ), cte2 as
   (select Comments,Value1, value as Value2 from CTE cross apply STRING_SPLIT(Value1,':') 
 )
 select comments,STRING_AGG(Value2,',' ) from cte2  
 where Value2>0
 group by Comments
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    coalesce(nullif(substring(col,  1, 5) + ','), ','), '') +
    coalesce(nullif(substring(col, 28, 5) + ','), ','), '') +
    coalesce(nullif(substring(col, 55, 5) + ','), ','), '') +
    coalesce(nullif(substring(col, 82, 5) + ','), ','), '') +    
    coalesce(nullif(substring(col,109, 5) + ','), ','), '') +         
    coalesce(nullif(substring(col,136, 5) + ','), ','), '')
from T
```

or

```
select
    replace(replace(replace(
        substring(col,  1, 5) + ',' +
        substring(col, 28, 5) + ',' +
        substring(col, 55, 5) + ',' +
        substring(col, 82, 5) + ',' +
        substring(col,109, 5) + ',' +
        substring(col,136, 5) + ','
    ',,,', ','), ',,', ','), ',,', ',')
from T
```